# Can i add/change password of another user in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to make a user management app where is want to give my user with admin privileges to create users and define their password and role as well. Also, in future admin can be able to change the password. Is that possible in the meteor ? I'm using the core `accounts-password` package.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Make use of server side methods. First, create a server side method that creates a user with [`Accounts.createUser(options, [callback])`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser). You can set the user's password and role (within the profile) in the options.

Then, create another server side method which calls [`Accounts.setPassword(userId, password, options)`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-setPassword) to change the user's password.

Comment: it's giving error `Exception while invoking method 'employee.insert' Error: Accounts.createUser with callback not supported on the server yet.`

Comment: Follow the link to the docs. It says the callback is client only (in other words, don't include a callback when using it on the server, just use the options).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the server side method `Accounts.setPassword(userId, password, options)` to set a user's password.